# Wordpress - get_permalink to return page_id instead of slug in %postname% permalink setting

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have wordpress site with `http://example.com/%postname%/` in permalink setting.

I want to `echo get_permalink()`, which showing `http://example.com/?page_id=xx` result

but when I did `echo get_permalink()`, it's return `http://example.com/some-slug/`. I know it's not an error because the permalink setting is %postname%.

I want to use it like this :
`echo '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'&get_weather='. $weather .'"></a>';`

to make link result like this :
`<a href="http://example.com/?page_id=1&get_weather=rain"></a>`

instead of this result:
`<a href="http://example.com/some-slug/&get_weather=rain"></a>`

So, is it possible to get result of `http://example.com/?page_id=xx`
while `echo`-ing `get_permalink()` with %postname% (or other permalink setting option) as the permalink
setting? please explain how

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the url manually

```
<?php 
  $url = add_query_arg( array('page_id' => get_the_ID(), 'get_weather' => 'rain'), home_url('/') );
?>
```

Comment: Just get confused of that, not thinking of your very simple code!